# Override template parameter in the script

Tags: powershell, azure

I am deploying VMs using a template and parameter file. I would like to override the parameter files virtualMachineName, so I can dynamically name each VM without needing 10 different parameter files. What is the correct syntax to do so?

Currently I have:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "myRSG" -TemplateFile $server1TmpFile  -TemplateParameterFile $serverParamFile -virtualMachineName "AS1FTW12"  -networkInterfaceName "AS1FTW12NIC" -networkSecurityGroupName "MyNSGName"
```

This will produce an error: 
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'virtualMachineName'

I am authoring the script using PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2017. My installed PowerShell AzureRM version is 5.1.1 according to Get-Module AzureRM.

Comment: AzureRM version and other information added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Works with AzureRM 5.1.1, you can test with the following setup:

template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "paramTest": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "result": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('paramTest')]"
        }
    }
}
```

parameters:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "paramTest": {
            "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
        }
    }
}
```

Powershell:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName rg -TemplateFile template.json -TemplateParameterFile param.json -paramTest somevalue
```

results in output value equal to the one passed from powershell

Your error indicates that the parameter name is wrong, doublé check it