# How to pass the output of one ARM template to the input parameter of the next ARM template in Continuous Deployment using VSTS?

Tags: arm, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a ServiceBuswithQueue ARM template that has the output section like this below:

```
  "outputs": {
    "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]"
    },
    "namespaceConnectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryConnectionString]"
    },
    "sharedAccessPolicyPrimaryKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryKey]"
    },
    "serviceBusQueueName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('serviceBusQueueName')]"
    }
  }
```

For that I Created the Continuous Integration (CI) and Continuous Deployment (CD) in VSTS, In CD I have used the PowerShell task to deploy the above ARM template. But I want to pass the output of this ARM template like "$(serviceBusQueueName)" to input parameter of the next ARM template in Continuous Deployment.

In know the above scenario can achieved using ARM outputs in between the two ARM task in Continuous Deployment. But I don’t want it because currently I am using the PowerShell task to deploy the ARM template.

Before posting this question, I was researched and find the following links but those are not helpful to resolve my issue.

[Azure ARM templates - using the output of other deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058494/azure-arm-templates-using-the-output-of-other-deployments)

[How do I use ARM 'outputs' values another release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948549/how-do-i-use-arm-outputs-values-another-release-task)

Can anyone please suggest me how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Do you mean you are deploying ARM templates together in a PowerShell task?

Comment: Yes Starian, currently I am using PowerShell task to deploy the ARM templates.

Comment: Can you use the output directly? For example: `$r=New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment ....`, then you can access $r directly in the sample script.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, Actually my first ARM template will give the output as "serviceBusNamespaceName". but I want to use the output of the first ARM templates into input parameter of the next ARM template.

Comment: You can override parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can override parameters by specifying corresponding parameters.

[Override template parameter in the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302111/override-template-parameter-in-the-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Start the deployment
Write-Host "Starting deployment...";
$outputs = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Mode Incremental -TemplateFile $templateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $parametersFilePath;

foreach ($key in $outputs.Outputs.Keys){
    $type = $outputs.Outputs.Item($key).Type
    $value = $outputs.Outputs.Item($key).Value
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;]$value"
}
```

You can display all the environment variables in a subsequent script:

```
Write-Host "Environment variables:"
gci env:* | sort-object name
```